# 2D array with floats

Tags: pgfmath

The following code is working for integers in `\myArray`, but not for floats. How can I make this code working for floats?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(0, -1)}, rotate=-45]
    \path (0.5, -0.5) node{1} ++(1, 0) node{2}
            ++(1, 0) node{3}  ++(1, 0) node{4}
            ++(1, 0) node{5}  ++(1, 0) node{6};
    \path (-0.5, 0.5) node{1} ++(0, 1) node{2}
            ++(0, 1) node{2}  ++(0, 1) node{3}
            ++(0, 1) node{4}  ++(0, 1) node{5};
    \def\myArray{{{1,5,3,4,5,6},
        {1,2,3,4,5},
        {1,2,3,4},
        {1,9.2,3},
        {1,2},
        {1}}}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,5} {
        \foreach \x in {0,...,\y} {
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\r}{\myArray[\x][\y-\x]}
            \draw (\x, \y - \x) rectangle +(1, 1);
            \node at (\x + 0.5, \y - \x + 0.5) {\r};
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: try using `\pgfmathsetmacro` instead of `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`. From `89.1 Commands for Parsing Expressions` of the PGF manual (two or three lines above the `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`).

Comment: works like a charm! Should i remove this question, because of low quality? If you think this is worth it you can answer the question, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\pgfmathsetmacro` instead of `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`. From section 89.1 Commands for Parsing Expressions of the PGF manual (two or three lines above the \pgfmathtruncatemacro)

> `\pgfmathsetmacro{hmacroi}{hexpressioni}` Defines hmacroi as the value
>   of hexpressioni. The result is a decimal without units.
>   `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{hmacroi}{hexpressioni}` Defines hmacroi as the
>   truncated value of hexpressioni.

I've tried it only for one decimal place though.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(0, -1)}, rotate=-45]
    \path (0.5, -0.5) node{1} ++(1, 0) node{2}
            ++(1, 0) node{3}  ++(1, 0) node{4}
            ++(1, 0) node{5}  ++(1, 0) node{6};
    \path (-0.5, 0.5) node{1} ++(0, 1) node{2}
            ++(0, 1) node{2}  ++(0, 1) node{3}
            ++(0, 1) node{4}  ++(0, 1) node{5};
    \def\myArray{{{1.1,5.1,3.2,4.3,5.4,6.3},
        {1,3.2,3,4,5.2},
        {0.1,2,3,4},
        {1,9.2,3},
        {3.1,2},
        {1}}}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,5} {
        \foreach \x in {0,...,\y} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\myArray[\x][\y-\x]}
            \draw (\x, \y - \x) rectangle +(1, 1);
            \node at (\x + 0.5, \y - \x + 0.5) {\r};
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: with decimals]